# hg convert: take in account svn:mergeinfo

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, mercurial

I made general web search and didn't find ever attempt to take in account `svn:mergeinfo` property  during repo conversion.

[Some people](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2011/12/subversion-to-mercurial-migration-using.html) fix merges manually.That is not case for large history.

I have simple merge history where `branches/dev` merged to `trunk` for releases (I know that it differ from official workflow recommendation).

Merge info I get from merging branch (`trunk` in my case) by:

```
cd trunk
svn log -g
```

I wrote parser for output in Bash which generate `--splicemap` format:

```
uuid=svn:`svn info | sed -n '/UUID: /{s=.*UUID: ==;p;q}'`

fbr=/branches/dev
tbr=/trunk

hunkstate=last-merged
linestate=header

error() {
  echo ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}: hunkstate: $hunkstate, linestate: $linestate
  exit 1
}

svn log -g | while read a1 a2 a3 rest; do
  if [[ $linestate = header ]]; then
    if [[ $a1 = '------------------------------------------------------------------------' ]]; then
      linestate=rev
    fi
    continue
  fi
  case $hunkstate in
    last-merged)
      case $linestate in
        rev)
          rev=${a1#r}
          linestate=merge
          ;;
        merge)
          if [[ $a1 = Merged && $a2 = "via:" ]]; then
            last_merged=$rev
            merged_to=${a3#r}
            hunkstate=merge
          fi
          linestate=header
          ;;
        *) error ;;
      esac
      ;;
    merge)
      case $linestate in
        rev)
          rev=${a1#r}
          linestate=merge
          ;;
        merge)
          if [[ $a1 = Merged && $a2 = "via:" ]]; then
            :
          else
            echo $uuid$tbr@$merged_to $uuid$tbr@$rev $uuid$fbr@$last_merged
            hunkstate=last-merged
          fi
          linestate=header
          ;;
        *) error ;;
      esac
      ;;
    *) error ;;
  esac
done
```

Next I run:

```
hg convert --splicemap merge.map svn://$IP/$BASE
```

Next step I fix convention about branch naming:

```
$ cat branch.map
default stable
dev default
$ hg convert --branchmap branch.map proj-hg/ proj-fixed
```

`hg glog`look nice. Some times I merge only selected parts of changes, holding rest to next release. When this happen history look strange:

```
| |
o |    changeset:   1988:214b38931712
|\ \   branch:      dev
| | |  parent:      1987:d3fc2c0f10ec
| | |  parent:      1969:8957aab1efa8
| | |
| o |  changeset:   1987:d3fc2c0f10ec
| |\|  branch:      dev
| | |  parent:      1964:9277a34e037f
| | |  parent:      1986:2194f9f673b1
| | |
| | o  changeset:   1974:b06706659b0e
| | |
| | o  changeset:   1973:5071aa6f3ee7
| | |
| | o  changeset:   1971:f9eea3a18947
| | |
+---o  changeset:   1970:20b9cd2fdce8
| |    user:
| |
o |  changeset:   1969:8957aab1efa8
| |
o |  changeset:   1968:921d85f051e1
```

but this happen rare.

Are any way to use `svn:merginfo` when convert repository from SVN to HG?